# In what sense is the column space of a symmetric matrix equivalent to its row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

I have an elementary question about linear dependence and column/row spaces.

Suppose we have a matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix}$, and we construct the matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&6\end{bmatrix}$ as a combination of the rows of $A$.

**We are asked whether the columns of $B$ are a combination of the columns of $A$.**

Just by looking at the first column $b_1$, it sure seems like there is not going to be any way of representing this as linear combinations of the columns of $A$.

**But**, I recall that for a symmetric matrix $A=A^\text{T}$, the column space and row space are "equivalent". But $\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}\not\in C(A)$!

So there is clearly some form of error in my understanding and reasoning here. Please, may somebody enlighten me? I would guess it's a misunderstanding I have about in what way the column space and row space are related in a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Why would you expect the column space to remain constant after modifying the rows?  So... while the matrix is currently symmetrical the column space and the row space are essentially the same (*though depending on interpretation, the one may be made of row-vectors while the other is made of column-vectors*).  And sure, multiplying a row by a nonzero constant will keep the rowspace the same but it will potentially change the column space!  The matrix is no longer symmetrical after such a modification.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ahh, of course. This is the insight I was missing. Thanks for the extremely speedy and useful response!

Comment: Consider by analogy... two children playing with blocks, $R$ and $C$.  $R$ looks from west to east, and $C$ looks from south to north.  They begin with the blocks in the configuration $\begin{matrix}\color{red}{\star}&\\&\color{blue}{\star}\end{matrix}$.  They are laying on the ground and can't discern distance very well, but from both $C$ and $R$'s perspectives they see the red block on the left and the blue block on the right.  $R$ then pushes a single block further to $\begin{matrix}&\color{red}{\star}\\\color{blue}{\star}\end{matrix}$.  From $R$'s perspective they look same but not to $C$.

Comment: The action of pushing a block towards or away from you doesn't change your personal perspective, but can change the perspective of the other player.  The same thing happens here, by modifying a row via multiplication by a nonzero constant the rowspace doesn't change, but the column space certainly can as a result.